# 'Insert' Cursor for Terminal on Mac OS

Tags: macos, terminal, text-cursor

My terminal is using the 'insert' cursor, like a block instead of a line, and I want to change it back to a normal cursor. This just randomly started happening and I don't know how to fix it - pressing 'Insert' on the keyboard doesn't do anything.

What my cursor looks like in terminal (problem):
[image: bad cursor]

What my cursor looks like everywhere else (how I want it in terminal too):
[image: good cursor]

Comment: Friendly FYI: images are 404 now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Settings window: *command + ,*

In the **Cursor** section select **Vertical Bar**:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKzBS.pngenter image description here]

Comment: @LearnRailsDrinkCoffee Glad to help :-)

Comment: One question: There's a space behind my cursor bar - do you know how to remove that space?

Comment: @LearnRailsDrinkCoffee Not sure how to fix this... maybe your `PS1` env var might contain some garbage?

Comment: Hmm... the only thing my bash_profile contains is: `export PS1="\W"
export CLICOLOR=YES`

Comment: Update: Found a cheeky space in the bash_profile... I removed that and now the space behind the cursor has gone :)

Comment: @rubyandcoffee Nice :-)